# Which algorithm is better, Z-algo or KMP-algo for pattern search?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-matching

Time complexity for both the algorithms is O(m+n).

n and m being the lengths of the text and the pattern to be searched.

The space complexity for Z algo is O(m+n) and the space complexity for the KMP algo is O(n).

I want to know which algorithm is practically faster and which one should be used generally ?

Comment: In practice some algorithms with O(m*n) are even faster, such as Boyer-Moore-Horspool. But yet string search performance heavily dependes on the size of the pattern and the size of the used alphabet, so there is no global ranking of algorithms.

Comment: Benchmark them for your own purposes with your own distribution of texts and patterns. In some cases these algorithms do not even beat brute-force search.

Comment: Thank You for your inputs .

Answer (score 0):

practically KMP is a better option and it works good in count of multiple matches also.
As already mentioned it is space efficient also.
and the logic behind both of them is same so speed difference will be minimum.